# The supremum of a sequence of definite integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am interested to find the supremum of the following sequence of definite integrals:
$$
I_n=\int_0^\pi\sqrt{4\cos^2((2n+1)x)+4\cos((2n+1)x)\cos(x)+1}\,\textrm{d}x,\ n\ge 1.
$$
One of my ideas was to use the inequality $\cos^2(x)\le 1$ in order to obtain the following majorization:
$$
I_n\ge\int_0^\pi|2\cos((2n+1)x)\cos(x)+1|\,\textrm{d}x.
$$
Unfortunately, this majorization is not as strong as necessary.

Comment: Note we also have $I_n\ge\int_0^\pi|2\cos((2n+1)x)+\cos(x)|\,\textrm{d}x.$

Comment: My friend, that is a VERY cool looking integral. The maximum value appears to be attained for $n=1$ though. Did you perhaps mean infinum? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28sqrt%284*%28cos%28%2821%29x%29%29%5E2%2B4*cos%28%2821%29x%29*cos%28x%29%2B1%29%2C0%2Cpi%29

Comment: No. What I need in my work is the supremum. But I agree that the problem could be quite difficult. It is not very clear for me what you indicated. In any case I would like to have a proof (the use a mathematical software can only give me a suggestion, I assume).

Comment: The maximum value of $I_n$ seems to be attained for $n=1$ is what I am saying. This is hence the supremum. $I_n$ does seem to converge though as $n->\infty$

Comment: After looking into it carefully, the supremum is definitely $I_1$. As $n->\infty$ $I_n->4.94674...$.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to show that $I_n$ indeed converges.
\begin{align}
J_n &= \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{4\cos^2 nx+4\cos nx\cos x+1}\,\textrm{d}x \\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\sqrt{4\cos^2 x+4\cos x\cos\frac{x}{n}+1}\,\textrm{d}x \\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\sqrt{4\cos^2 x+4\cos x\cos\frac{k\pi}{n}+1}\,\textrm{d}x+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{4\cos^2 x+4\cos x\cos\frac{k\pi}{n}+1}\,\textrm{d}x+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_0^1\sqrt{4\cos^2 x+4\cos x\cos\pi y+1}\,\textrm{d}y\,\textrm{d}x+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align}

So as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $$I_n\rightarrow \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_0^\pi\sqrt{4\cos^2 x+4\cos x\cos y+1}\,\textrm{d}y\,\textrm{d}x=4.946...$$

Comment: Nice!! How did you think of this?

Comment: @coolydudey60 Well, after the substitution $nx=t$, the riemann sum came into mind and things went smooth afterwards.

Comment: I'm working on something simpler and more general as well as generalising to $n \in \mathbb{R}$. Nice work!

Comment: It turns out the way you did it is the simplest. We have that what you wrote holds in general for $f(\cos(nx),x)$ (to be interpreted the obvious way), where here we have $f=\sqrt{4\cos^2 nx+4\cos nx\cos x+1}$. Generalising to $n \in \mathbb{R}$ is just a case of showing the error is small when compared to the closest integer, which is easy. I think this is a very cool result... It could even make for some really mean exam questions!!

Comment: Nice proof. Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify what I mean by general case: $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(cos(nx),x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(cos(x),y)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: @cooleydudey60 That is kinda interesting. Could you kindly also clarify the conditions $f$ needs to have in your generalized case? (like continuity(for the $O(1/n)$), being a even function(for interchanging the order of integration and summation), etc)

Comment: well, clearly continuity, we're not just talking about any old integrable function. I'm sorry, I'm not sure I see why you need it to be an even function; we're only on positive numbers here. It's not immediately obvious if we need anything else, other than being defined on the full closed interval (I should think it could fail if it was unbounded and undefined at one of the endpoints).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to illustrate what I mean. Here is a plot of $I_n$ for $1 \leq n \leq 20$:

[image]

Did this in MATLAB. The behaviour continues for $n \leq 2000$, but I'm not including a plot. I think a conjecture is clear, but I can't give a proof right now I'm afraid.

For purposes of pure interest, here is what happens when we let $n$ be real.

This is a plot of $I_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $1 \leq n \leq 30$:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. The problem remains open. I will try to prove your conjecture.